# How to apply reactivity when passing a props that imported from Pinia via storeToRefs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, pinia

In this code, a Pinia store is utilized to manage the invoiceLines state.
These invoiceLines array is imported into InvoiceLine.vue using storeToRefs and then passed to InvoiceLineEdit.vue.

It's important to mention that the functions addInvoiceLine, updateInvoiceLine, and removeInvoiceLine are functioning correctly, and the changes made to the invoiceLines, either the update and the delete) are accurately reflected in the store and can be seen by the console. However, there is an issue with the deletion of a line in the vue. Although the InvoiceLines array itself appears to be correct, the change is not being accurately reflected within InvoiceLineEdit.vue. In other words, whenever you delete a line, the last invoiceLine is deleted but not the one that you selected!

The complete code:

> 1- The Pinia store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useInvoiceStore = defineStore('InvoiceStore', {
  state: () => ({
    invoiceLines: [],
  }),
  actions: {
    //add invoice line item
    addInvoiceLine(newLine) {
      this.invoiceLines.push(newLine)
    },

    //update invoice line Item
    updateInvoiceLine(oldProductId, newLine) {
      this.invoiceLines = this.invoiceLines.map( line => {
        // If the productId matches, replace the lineItem with the new line item
        if (line.productId === oldProductId) {
          return newLine
        }
    
        // Otherwise, keep the original lineItem
        return line
      })
    },

    //remove invoice line item
    removeInvoiceLine(productId) {
      this.invoiceLines = this.invoiceLines.filter(obj => obj.productId !== productId)
    },
  },
})
```

> 2- The InvoiceLine.vue:

```
<script setup>
import InvoiceLineEdit from './InvoiceLineEdit.vue'
import { useInvoiceStore } from '@/stores/useInvoiceStore'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { watch } from 'vue'

const BLANK_ITEM_BASE =  {
  productId: 0,
  description: '',
  unitPrice: 0,
  quantity: 1,
  discount: 0,
  vat: 0,
}

const invoiceStore = useInvoiceStore()
const { addInvoiceLine, updateInvoiceLine, removeInvoiceLine } = invoiceStore
const { invoiceLines } = storeToRefs(invoiceStore)

/**
 * Get the invoice data from the Invoice store directally
 */
const AllLinesHaveProductId = () => {
  return invoiceLines.value.every( obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('productId') && obj.productId !== 0 )
} 

//  Add item function
const addLineItem = () => {
  if(invoiceLines.value.length === 0 ) {
    addInvoiceLine(BLANK_ITEM_BASE)
  }
  else if(AllLinesHaveProductId()) {
    addInvoiceLine(BLANK_ITEM_BASE)
  }
  else {
    console.log('Deelete the dublicated lines before you add a new line')
  }
}

const updateLineItem = (oldProductId, newLine) => {
  updateInvoiceLine(oldProductId, newLine)
}

const removeLineItem = productId => {
  removeInvoiceLine(productId)
}
</script>

<template>
  <!-- SECTION Invoice lines -->
  <VCardText>
    <div
      v-for="(line, index) in invoiceLines"
      :key="index"
      class="my-4 ma-sm-4"
    >
      <InvoiceLineEdit
        :index="index"
        :data="line"
        @remove-line="removeLineItem"
        @update-line="updateLineItem"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="mt-4 ma-sm-4">
      <VBtn @click="addLineItem">
        Add Line Item
      </VBtn>
    </div>
  </VCardText>
</template>
```

> 3-The InvoiceLineEdit.vue:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch, computed, toRaw } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  index: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: -1,
  },
  data: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
})

const emit = defineEmits([
  'removeLine',
  'updateLine',
  'totalAmount',
])

const selectedItem = ref()

const lineItem = ref(structuredClone(toRaw(props.data)))

const itemsOptions = [
  {
    productId: 111,
    title: 'App Design',
    unitPrice: 24,
    description: 'Designed UI kit & app pages.',
    vatRate: 15,
  },
  {
    productId: 222,
    title: 'App Customization',
    unitPrice: 26,
    description: 'Customization & Bug Fixes.',
    vatRate: 15,
  },
  {
    productId: 333,
    title: 'ABC Template',
    unitPrice: 28,
    description: 'Vuetify admin template.',
    vatRate: 15,
  },
  {
    productId: 444,
    title: 'App Development',
    unitPrice: 32,
    description: 'Native App Development.',
    vatRate: 15,
  },
]

const totalPrice = computed( ()=> {
  if(!lineItem.value) return

  return lineItem.value.unitPrice + lineItem.value.quantity - lineItem.value.discount
} )

const totalIncludVAT = ref(0)

watch(selectedItem, (newProductId, oldProductId) => {
  console.log('selectedIten-ProductId', newProductId, oldProductId)
  
  //replacing undefined with ZERO
  const conditionalOldProductId = oldProductId === undefined ? 0 : oldProductId

  const item = itemsOptions.filter(obj => {
    return obj.productId === newProductId
  })

  lineItem.value.productId = item[0].productId
  lineItem.value.unitPrice = item[0].unitPrice
  lineItem.value.vatRate = item[0].vatRate
  lineItem.value.description = item[0].description


  emit('updateLine', conditionalOldProductId, lineItem.value)
})


watch(totalPrice, () => {
  if(lineItem.value) {
    console.log('Total update', lineItem.value)

    const result =  totalPrice.value * 0.15 
    
    totalIncludVAT.value = Number(totalPrice.value) + Number(result.vat) 
    lineItem.value.vat = result.vat
    lineItem.value.total = totalPrice.value
    emit('updateLine', props.index, lineItem.value)
  }
}, { immediate: true })

//To triger the Line remve event on parent
const removeLine = () => {
  emit('removeLine', lineItem.value.productId)
}
</script>


<template>
  <div class="mb-4 d-none d-md-flex ps-5 pe-16">
    <VRow class="font-weight-medium">
      <VCol
        cols="12"
        md="6"
      >
        <span class="text-base">
          Item
        </span>
      </VCol>

      <VCol
        cols="12"
        md="2"
      >
        <span class="text-base">
          Unit Price
        </span>
      </VCol>

      <VCol
        cols="12"
        md="2"
      >
        <span class="text-base">
          Quantity
        </span>
      </VCol>

      <VCol
        cols="12"
        md="2"
      >
        <span class="text-base">
          Price
        </span>
      </VCol>
    </VRow>
  </div>

  <VCard
    flat
    border
    class="d-flex flex-row"
  >
    <!--  Left Form -->
    <div class="pa-5 flex-grow-1">
      <VRow>
        <!-- first column -->
        <VCol
          cols="12"
          md="6"
        >
          <!-- selected item -->
          <VSelect
            v-model="selectedItem"
            :items="itemsOptions"
            item-title="title"
            item-value="productId"
            label="Select Item"
            class="mb-3"
          />
          <!-- description -->
          <VTextarea
            v-model="lineItem.description"
            rows="4"
            label="Description"
            placeholder="Description"
          />
        </VCol>
        <!-- second column -->
        <VCol
          cols="12"
          md="2"
          sm="4"
        >
          <!-- Unit Price -->
          <VTextField
            v-model="lineItem.unitPrice"
            type="number"
            label="Unit Price"
            class="mb-3"
          />
          <!-- total -->
          <VTextField
            v-model="lineItem.total"
            type="number"
            label="Total"
            disabled
          />
        </VCol>
        <!-- third cilumn -->
        <VCol
          cols="12"
          md="2"
          sm="4"
        >
          <!-- quantity -->
          <VTextField
            v-model="lineItem.quantity"
            type="number"
            label="Quantity"
            class="mb-3"
          />
          <!-- VAT -->
          <VTextField
            v-model="lineItem.vat"
            type="number"
            label="VAT"
            disabled
          />          
        </VCol>
        <!-- fourth column -->
        <VCol
          cols="12"
          md="2"
          sm="4"
        >
          <!-- discount -->
          <VTextField
            v-model="lineItem.discount"
            type="number"
            label="Discount"
            class="mb-3"
          />
          <!-- total include vat -->
          <VTextField
            v-model="totalIncludVAT"
            type="number"
            label="Total Include VAT"
            disabled
          />          
        </VCol>
      </VRow>
    </div>

    <!--  Item Actions -->
    <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-space-between border-s pa-1">
      <IconBtn @click="removeLine">
        <VIcon
          size="20"
          icon="tabler-trash"
        />
      </IconBtn>
    </div>
  </VCard>
</template>
```

Comment: Please, provide a way to reproduce the problem. The example is too bulky and needs to be debugged. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . A potential problem is `:key="index"`. If you identify lines by ids it's a mistake to rely on an index. Since InvoiceLineEdit gets lineItem once on mount, not remounting it on invoiceLines update may potentially lead to the describe problem.

Comment: Your comment involves the answer! you are right, the issue has been resolved by using productId instead of index `:key="productId"`.